# BASH - How to use find with $@ when $@ includes nonexistent file?

Tags: bash, unix

I have a function that is passed a several file names as arguments. There's the possibility that some of the file names refer to files that don't exist or have been deleted. Because there may also be directories among the args, I want to get a recursive list of all the files passed as args and all of the files contained in the directories that may be included as args.

```
function SomeFunction () {
  # get list of files recursively
  fList=$(find $@ -type f) 
  do something with $fList
  .
  .
  .
}

[~]$SomeFunction existentFile nonexistentFile existentNonEmptyDir
find: `nonexistentFile': No such file or directory
```

`fList=$(find $@ -type f)` would work great if it weren't for `nonexistentFile`. Is there a way to make this same call even with a missing file?

Comment: `$@` needs to be in quotes -- `"$@"` -- to work correctly. Otherwise it's identical to an unquoted use of `$*`

Comment: Beyond that, could you try to produce a [mcve] -- code someone else can run without changes to produce your error themselves?

Comment: ...note also that `fList=$( ... )` is inherently buggy -- you're trying to store a list of strings in a variable that is itself a string. There's no 100% reliable way to tell when one filename ends and the next one begins (keep in mind that newline literals are themselves legal inside filenames). See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29

Comment: It already works, the missing files/dirs will just be skipped. You can suppress the warning if you want

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly reasonable to just ignore the warning from `find`. However, if you want to filter your argument list for things that actually exist before its invocation, you can do that explicitly:

```
SomeFunction() {
  local -a existing_args=( )
  for arg in "$@"; do
    [[ -e "$arg" ]] && existing_args+=( "$arg" )
  done
  while IFS= read -r -d '' result; do
    printf 'Processing result: %q\n'  ## put your own code here
  done < <(find "${existing_args[@]}" -type f -print0)
}
```

Some points of note:

- The `function` keyword is taken from ksh function declaration syntax of `function SomeFunction {`; the parens following the function name are taken from the POSIX sh function declaration syntax of `SomeFunction() {`. Combining both of them has a result which is compatible with neither legacy ksh nor POSIX sh. See http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete
- Quoting `"$@"` ensures that filenames with spaces, glob characters, etc. are handled correctly; likewise on an array expansion, such as `"${existing_args[@]}"`.
- `existing_args` is defined as an array -- a list of strings -- rather than an individual string. This is important, because filenames are themselves strings, and attempting to iterate over a string as if it were a list is generally buggy (again impacting files with spaces, literal newlines, glob characters, etc in their names).
- Using `find -print0` ensures that we're NUL-delimiting our filenames. This is important because filenames in UNIX are passed around as NUL-delimited strings internally; NUL is thus the only character guaranteed not to be present in a path. `IFS= read -r -d '' var` reads a single entry from such a NUL-delimited string.
- Using `< <(...)` ensures that we're redirecting from `...`'s output to the loop which is the subject of that redirection, while putting `find` -- and not the loop -- in a subshell. For an example of why this is important, see [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Comment: I was going to comment that `find` is redundant if you're already checking for file existence, but then I realized that find would descend into any directoried given in the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

```
someFunction () {
    # remove nonexistent names from argument list
    for pathname do
        [ -e "$pathname" ] && set -- "$@" "$pathname"
        shift
    done

    # exit with failure if none of the given pathnames existed
    [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && return 1

    # find regular files in the given existing paths and process these
    find "$@" -type f -exec sh -c '
        for pathname do
            # process found regular file "$pathname"
        done' sh {} +
}
```

- Double quote `$@`, or the shell will perform word splitting and filename globbing on the elements.
- Don't save the output of `find` into a string.  That would break if any filename contained a space.